# Blinking labels don't appear upon return from second (modal) view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I've got two labels in a custom `UITableViewCell`. Their purpose is to indicate the status of a timing operation on the object represented by the cell.

One label displays a countup timer. The other simply blinks "Timer Sleeping." Their visibility is mutually exclusive (if one is visible, the other is not, and vice versa) according to a switch statement to determine which label is currently visible. Each is driven by a dedicated `NSTimer`.

Everything works fine--until I do a modal segue to another View Controller (for the purpose of adding another entity or other task) and then return to the original VC via `Cancel` or `Save`through delegation. Then, regardless of which label had been visible (and updating via its timer) prior to the segue, no label is to be seen. The cell appears blank.

The weird thing is that when I segue to yet another VC via a push segue, then return via the "Home" button, the labels appear, blinking or counting up, just as though nothing had happened. The only obvious difference I can see between the two return methods is that the modal is handled via delegation whereas the push is unwound through a nav controller.

Any ideas? I can supply any relevant code, but didn't know where to start and didn't want to paste all of it.

Thanks!

**EDIT for clarification in response to question below:**

I'm returning via delegation. Here's the code in the modal:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if (self.activityField.text.length > 0)
    {
        if (self.categoryLabel.text.length < 1)
        {
//            self.thisActivity.category = @"Uncategorized";
//            self.thisActivity.name =self.activityField.text;
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No category selected"
                                                            message:@"Please select a category or Cancel"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

        }

        else
        {
            self.thisCategory.name = self.categoryLabel.text;
            self.thisActivity.name = self.activityField.text;
            self.thisActivity.category = self.thisCategory.name;

            NSLog(@"Category name is %@", self.thisCategory.name);
            NSLog(@"Activity name is %@", self.thisActivity.name);
            [self.delegate addActivityViewControllerDidSave];
        }
    }

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No activity entered"
                                                        message:@"Please enter a new activity or Cancel"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{    
    [self.delegate addActivityViewControllerDidCancel:self.thisActivity];
    NSLog(@"delegate is %@",self.delegate);

}
```

And here's the delegate method implementation code from the original VC:

```
#pragma mark - AddViewControllerDelegate stuff

-(void) addActivityViewControllerDidSave
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];
}

-(void) addActivityViewControllerDidCancel:(WMDGActivity *) activityToDelete
{
    [activityToDelete MR_deleteEntity];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];
}
```

**2nd edit:**

Here's the `refreshData` code:

```
-(void) refreshData
{
    actFRC = [WMDGActivity MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"category,name"
                                  ascending:YES withPredicate:nil
                                    groupBy:@"category"
                                   delegate:nil];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

I've tried calling this method in viewDidLoad, and NOT calling it there. Same results.

**UPDATE, 3/26/2014:**

OK, I've discovered that if I remove the call to `refreshData` from my `addActivityViewControllerDidCancel` method, the labels work fine. They likewise work fine if I remove the same line from `addActivityViewControllerDidSave`. Unfortunately, this prevents newly added items from appearing in the `HomeViewController` table view until the app is relaunched.

Here is my current code for the cancel and save methods:

```
-(void) addActivityViewControllerDidSave
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];
}

-(void) addActivityViewControllerDidCancel:(WMDGActivity *) activityToDelete
{
    [activityToDelete MR_deleteEntity];
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
//    [self refreshData];
}
```

I view this as a temporary, or interim, fix. Sure would be grateful for a real cure.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you returning from your modal vc? Also, you should post your delegate method.

Comment: Please see edit above!

Comment: Have you logged self.delegate to make sure it's not nil?

Comment: The log says "_delegate HomeViewController * 0x8d36920 0x08d36920"

Comment: Ay caramba! I just glanced at this again on my ipad after shutting down my MBP, and realize I copied code from the wrong VC. Will correct first thing in the morning.

Comment: Edit fixed--contains correct code.

Comment: Are you doing something in `refreshData` that could cause your labels to stop blinking? Is this method also called when you return from the navController-pushed VC?

Comment: @Stonz2--I posted my refreshData code in 2nd edit above.

Comment: Please see update in question!